# Angular 7 Drop down list inside material table data source is selecting the last item of the array

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material, angular7, angular-material-6

I have this form group inside an angular material table having data source;

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="fr">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Family Rel. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-form-field color="warn" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Family Relation</mat-label>
             <mat-select id="family_relation" formControlName="family_relation" placeholder="Family Relation">
                   <mat-option *ngFor="let familyRelation of familyRelationArray; let i = index" [value]="familyRelation.family_relation_id">
                        {{familyRelation.family_relation_type}}
                   </mat-option>
             </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
                  {{element.fr}}
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

I am getting `familyRelationArray` from this method:

```
getFamilyRelation() {
    let status = 'Active';
    this.auth.getFamilyRelation(status).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.familyRelationArray = data;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

For each row displayed in my material table, their is a different family relation.

I am displaying data using the following:

```
getData()
  {
    this.auth.getIndPerHousehold(this.hh_id).subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        if(data=="empty")
        {
          this.showEmpty = true;
        }
        else
        {
          this.showEmpty = false;
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(Object.values(data));
          this.resultsLength = Object.values(data).length;
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
          // this.formGroup.controls['family_relation'].setValue(Object.values(data[0]['frid']));
          Object.values(data).forEach(element => {
            //console.log(element.frid)
            this.formGroup.get('family_relation').setValue(element.frid);
          });
        }
      },
      (error)=>
      {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

I am using the following to select the correspondent relation of each individual in the family:

```
Object.values(data).forEach(element => {
    //console.log(element.frid)
    this.formGroup.get('family_relation').setValue(element.frid);
});
```

What is displayed in the table is the regular data but the drop down lists are selecting the last imported value of `element.frid`.

So the last row is a child, all the drop down lists are selecting `child`.

[image]

Please note that `frid` is the same as family_relation_id.

How to run a loop inside datasource subscribe result to let the drop down list select the exact value of each row ?